# Boost write_xml to vector wrapped in back_insert_device yields 0 sized vector

Tags: c++, boost

In the code below, why does the vector 'v' have a size of 0? The code works fine if passing write_xml a stringstream. But I'd rather not have to pay the cost of string allocation when, eventually, dumping the text XML.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
  boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
  pt.put("file.name", "testf");
  pt.put("file.type", "xml");
  pt.put("file.size", 0);
  std::vector<char> v;
  back_insert_device<std::vector<char>> sink{v};
  stream<back_insert_device<std::vector<char>>> os{sink};
  boost::property_tree::write_xml(os, pt);
  std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to flush the stream. You can `os.flush()` or just let the destructor handle it:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5b6cd1bdf608986)**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.put("file.name", "testf");
    pt.put("file.type", "xml");
    pt.put("file.size", 0);

    std::vector<char> v;
    {
        back_insert_device<std::vector<char>>         sink{v};
        stream<back_insert_device<std::vector<char>>> os{sink};

        boost::property_tree::write_xml(os, pt);
    }
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
100
```

---

### BONUS

As always, use a JSON library!

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1fb87a3bc33e0e1)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace json = boost::json;

int main() {
    json::object file{
        {"name", "testf"},
        {"type", "xml"},
        {"size", 0},
    };

    auto v = serialize(json::object{{"file", file}});
    std::cout << v.size() << ": " << v << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
47: {"file":{"name":"testf","type":"xml","size":0}}
```

Comment: Ugh. I always forget to flush.